# Netty High Availability Cluster

Tags: netty, high-availability

Wondering if Netty has any examples of how I can create a high availability application whereby the netty client will use a backup server in case of live server failure.

Comment: Define "failure", define your required guarantees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the client and server highly available and to manage the connections state by your code with ease, Have a look on [Akka Remote Actor API](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.3-RC4/java/remote-actors.html) which is using Netty for underlying communication .

Comment: Akka Remote Actor API link is broken

Answer (score 0):

There is no example of this. But I think its quite straight-forward. You need to have a pool of different "channels" that are connected to remote hosts. The do something like this:

```
channel.write(msg).addListener() {
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
        if (!future.isSuccess) {
            ... // get next channel from the pool and try the write there etc..
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..